# Evaluate the Sum

Tags: summation

Evaluate
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{5n+1}{(2n+1)!}$$

I tried using $e^{x}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}$
But I got $$5e-8\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n+1}$$
Hints would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$5n+1=\dfrac52\left(2n+1\right)+1-\dfrac52$

$$\implies \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{5n+1}{(2n+1)!}=\dfrac52 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac1{(2n)!}-\dfrac32\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac1{(2n+1)!}$$

Now  we know $\displaystyle\sum_{r=0}^\infty\dfrac{y^r}{r!}=e^y$

Can you find $e^y+e^{-y}$ and $e^y-e^{-y}$

Here $y=1$

Answer (score 0):

Let $$(5n+1)=A(2n+1)+B \rightarrow 2A=5, A+B=1 \rightarrow $A=5/2, B=-3/2.$$
Then $$ S=\frac{5}{2} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2n!} -\frac{3}{2} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)!} = \frac{5}{2} \cosh 1 - \frac{3}{2} \sinh 1. $$